# In Spark (Scala) how to perform a user defined operation on grouped rows before shuffling?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 3.0.1 with Scala

I have a huge data set which has similar (entries)/rows I want to

1. Group rows by keys in their partitions.
2. Choose a subset of rows from each group within each partition.
3. Get the top rows by a column value per group across partitions.

Its easy enough to use an API function to perform this (Which I think does something similar with a standard SDK function)

```
  val df2 = df1
    .groupBy("group_key", df1.columns: _*)
    .min("length")
  
  df2
   .show()
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to perform a user defined function

I tried versions of:

```
def similar(l1: List[Row], l2: List[Row]): List[Row] = {
  //logic to choose non-similar rows and limit list size to avoid 
  // imbalanced partitions 
  l1 ++ l2
}

val aggFuntion = new Aggregator[Row, List[Row], List[Row]](
  createCombiner = List[Row],
  mergeValue = similar,
  mergeCombiners = similar
)

val aggUdaf = udaf[Row, List[Row], List[Row]](aggFuntion)


val df2 = df1
  .groupBy("group_key", df1.columns: _*)
  .agg(aggUdaf(col("fathers")))
  
df2
  .show()
```

but couldn't get the syntax to work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question I'm attempting to

1. Group by a key
2. Perform user defined action on each group (partially reducing rows)
3. Sort results
4. Limit the results for each group by sorting criteria

Rather than implement an Aggregator on a grouped DataFrame I just converted to RDD:

```
def partitionOperation = (acc: Array[Row], m: (Int, Iterable[Row])) => {

  val lowestNResultsPerGroupByCriterion: Array[Row] = m._2.foldLeft(Array[Row]())((acc, r) => {

    val criterion = r.getAs[Double](scoreCriterion)

    val acc1 = acc.length match {
      case a if a < resultsLimit => (acc :+ r).sortBy(r => r.getAs[Double](scoreCriterion))
      case a =>

        val i = 0
        var acc2 = acc

        acc.takeWhile(r1 => {
          val criterion1 = r1.getAs[Double](scoreCriterion)

          if (criterion < criterion1) {

            acc2 = acc.slice(0, i) ++ Array(r) ++ acc.slice(i, a)
          }

          criterion < criterion1
        })

        if (acc2.length > resultsLimit) {
          acc2.slice(0, resultsLimit)
        }
        else {
          acc2
        }
    }

    acc1
  })

  lowestNResultsPerGroupByCriterion
}

def crossPartitionOperation = (acc1: Array[Row], acc2: Array[Row]) => acc1 ++ acc2

val h = df
  .rdd
  .groupBy(r => r.getAs[Int](groupCriterion))
  .aggregate(Array[Row]())(partitionOperation, crossPartitionOperation)

h.foreach(r => {
  println(r)
})

val dff = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(h), df.schema
)

val f = dff
  //      .orderBy(groupCriterion)
  .orderBy(scoreCriterion)
//      .filter(r => r.getAs[Int](groupCriterion) == 5)

f.show(120)
println(s"Top $resultsLimit $scoreCriterion of each $groupCriterion.\nTotal results: ${f.count()}")
```